# How long can savory cream cheese dishes last?

Tags: storage-lifetime, cream-cheese

I made this recipe [here](http://allrecipes.com/recipe/delicious-black-bean-burritos/detail.aspx) and have some of the black bean, onion, cream cheese mixture left.  My question is .. how long will this last?  For some reason, the thought of heating down the cream cheese to become a sauce will not last very long..

Thanks for any recommendation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [North Dakota State University](http://www.ag.ndsu.edu/pubs/yf/foods/fn579-1.htm), cream cheese, opened should last about two weeks between 32'f and 40'f. For the cheese itself, unopened, they recommend to "Use within one week of the 'best when purchased by' date". Unfortunately, in this situation, you cannot simply cut away the mold from the cheese since it is a mixed dish.

When you factor in the fact that the cheese was not only unwrapped, but heated along with other components, and likely sat out for some time on the counter in addition to in the pan, with added protein (the black beans especially), the math for how long cream cheese can last in your fridge shrinks and shrinks.

Personally, I would follow the cooked meat guidelines to be on the safe side. This means that well-wrapped leftovers, quickly taken out of the danger zone range of temps ([40'f - 140'f](http://www.fsis.usda.gov/factsheets/how_temperatures...food/index.asp)), should last for 3-4 days after cooking.

Answer (score -2):

If there is no sensible data to support your question - I would just handle Cream cheese as if uncooked.  So if cooked before it's expiry date - treat it as if it will last until it's expiry date.

Cooking takes the cheese back to "square one" where the product is considered less enticing to bugs and bacteria.  There is no data to support this guess, thus I would just adhere to the expiry date of the cheese - regardless what you do to the cheese.

Comment: Expiry dates apply to unopened packages of cheese typically. Once opened it's a whole new ball of wax, or fat covered in wax as it were